# How to list the cloaked folders of a TFS workspace on a command line?

Tags: windows, tfs, command-line

I have some folders cloaked in the workspace. I need a way to list them on the command line. I am pretty sure I know how to do it using the TFS API, but I do not see how to do it with `tf`.

Neither `tf workspace` nor `tf workfold` seem to allow it or am I missing the obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tf workfold`command to list the working folders (including the cloaked folders) from a specific workspace:

```
tf workfold /workspace:YourWorkspaceName /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
```

Please see [Workfold Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/workfold-command?view=vsts) for details.

[image]

Comment: How could I miss it?